# Add delegate or event property to this class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events, delegates

I created a control where other developers can create an instance and use. There is a button click in the control. How do I allow developers to plug in their own code in a certain part of my control? I am not sure if or how exactly to use a delegate or event in this scenario. Can someone help in the below example:

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl
{
   ...
   void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //DO SOMETHING
      if (success)
      {
         //CALL DEVELOPER'S LOGIC
      }
   }
}
```

In the developers code, how can they pass in their logic when the button click of the control is successful?

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    var ctlMyControl = new MyControl();

    //ADD SuccessCode() TO ctlMyControl
    //SO IT IS TRIGGERED ON SUCCESS
    //MAYBE SOMETHING LIKE:
    //ctlMyControl.SuccessEvent = SuccessCode()??

    this.Control.Add(ctlMyControl);
}

protected void SuccessCode()
{
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

How to I update MyControl to allow this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt.aspx) to the control, like this:

```
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //DO SOMETHING
    if (success) {
        OnSomethingCompleted();
    }
}

///<summary>Occurs when the operation is successfully completed.</summary>
public event EventHandler SomethingCompleted;
///<summary>Raises the SomethingCompleted event.</summary>
internal protected virtual void OnSomethingCompleted() { OnSomethingCompleted(EventArgs.Empty); }
///<summary>Raises the SomethingCompleted event.</summary>
///<param name="e">An EventArgs object that provides the event data.</param>
internal protected virtual void OnSomethingCompleted(EventArgs e) {
    if (SomethingCompleted != null)
        SomethingCompleted(this, e);
}
```

In the form, you can add a handler to the event, like this:

```
myControl.SomethingCompleted += myControl_SomethingCompleted;

void myControl_SomethingCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Do things
}
```

For more information, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt.aspx).

Comment: I believe the signature for EventHandler is (object sender, EventArgs e) but your handler only has a signature of (EventArgs e).  I don't think that will work as is??

Comment: @Doug: This does work.  Read it more carefully; that's not a handler.

Comment: Ha yes I did misread that - Thanks for the tip below btw, I did not realize there was a static "Empty" member of the EventArgs class.

Answer (score 1):

Since your event uses the default signature of type EventHandler, you just need to expose a public event of type EventHandler.  So take a look at the code below.

**Here is how you implement the new event!**

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl
{
   //New public event declaration of type EventHandler
   public event EventHandler Submit_OnClick;

   void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //DO SOMETHING
      if (success)
      {
         //CALL DEVELOPER'S LOGIC

         //Code to raise the event only if there are subscribers.
         if (Submit_OnClick != null)
         {
           Submit_OnClick(this, new EventArgs());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Here is how you use the new event!**

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    var ctlMyControl = new MyControl();
      //Subscribed to the newly added event of your MyControl class
        ctlMyControl.Submit_OnClick += new EventHandler(SuccessCode);

    //ADD SuccessCode() TO ctlMyControl
    //SO IT IS TRIGGERED ON SUCCESS
    //MAYBE SOMETHING LIKE:
    //ctlMyControl.SuccessEvent = SuccessCode()??

    this.Control.Add(ctlMyControl);
}

//Modified the signature to be compliant with EventHandler type
protected void SuccessCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare the event, and if necessary create a custom event args class for passing information about the event.

Here is [a blog post](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/7/pageid/5.aspx) I wrote a while back that walks through the process.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event to the your control.

Something like this:

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl
{
       public event EventHandler Success;
       ...
       void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {   
       //DO SOMETHING
        if (success)
        {
             //CALL DEVELOPER'S LOGIC
             OnSuccess();
        }
   }

    private static void OnSuccess()
    {
         if(Success != null)
         {
              Success(this, EventArgs.Empty); //or you can pass event args you want. But you should use EventHandler<T> instead.
         }
    }
}
```

And than other developers can youse your control like this:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    var ctlMyControl = new MyControl();

    ctlMyConstrol += SuccessCode;

    this.Control.Add(ctlMyControl);
}

protected void SuccessCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

You can read more about events on MSDN.